Adding variable indentation in front of each line of python logging output
I am building logging into a python app, and I would like it to be human-readable. At the moment, the debug logs document every function that is called, with argument and return values. This means that practically, a debug log for a nested function call might look like this:
2024-07-29 16:52:26,641: DEBUG: MainController.initialize_components called with args <controllers.main_controller.MainController(0x1699fdcdda0) at 0x000001699F793300>
2024-07-29 16:52:26,643: DEBUG: MainController.setup_connections called with args <controllers.main_controller.MainController(0x1699fdcdda0) at 0x000001699F793300>
2024-07-29 16:52:26,645: DEBUG: MainController.setup_connections returned None
2024-07-29 16:52:26,646: DEBUG: MainController.initialize_components returned None

I would like to make it obvious from reading the logs when things are nested, using indentation, python-style. So the ideal output would be this:
2024-07-29 16:52:26,641: DEBUG: MainController.initialize_components called with args <controllers.main_controller.MainController(0x1699fdcdda0) at 0x000001699F793300>
    2024-07-29 16:52:26,643: DEBUG: MainController.setup_connections called with args <controllers.main_controller.MainController(0x1699fdcdda0) at 0x000001699F793300>
    2024-07-29 16:52:26,645: DEBUG: MainController.setup_connections returned None
2024-07-29 16:52:26,646: DEBUG: MainController.initialize_components returned None

I am currently achieving my documentation by wrapping class methods with this decorator:
import functools
import logging

def log(_func=None, *, logger):
    def decorator_log(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if logger.handlers:
                current_formatter = logger.handlers[0].formatter
                current_formatter.set_tabs(current_formatter.get_tabs() + 1)
            
            self = args[0]
            name = f'{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}'
            if logger.root.level < logging.DEBUG:
                logger.info(f"Entering {name}")
            else:
                args_repr = [repr(a) for a in args]
                kwargs_repr = [f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
                signature = ", ".join(args_repr + kwargs_repr)
                logger.debug(f"{name} called with args {signature}")
                try:
                    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.exception(f"Exception raised in {name}: {str(e)}")
                    raise e
                if logger.root.level < logging.DEBUG:
                    logger.info(f"Leaving {name}")
                else:
                    logger.debug(f"{name} returned {result}")

                if logger.handlers:
                    current_formatter = logger.handlers[0].formatter
                    current_formatter.set_tabs(current_formatter.get_tabs() - 1)
                
                return result
        return wrapper
    if _func is None:
        return decorator_log
    else:
        return decorator_log(_func)

I could add an attribute tabs to the logger with setattr and incremement at the start/decrement at the end of the decorator, but this only applies the tabs to the message portion of the output, like so:
2024-07-29 16:52:26,641: DEBUG: MainController.initialize_components called with args <controllers.main_controller.MainController(0x1699fdcdda0) at 0x000001699F793300>
2024-07-29 16:52:26,643: DEBUG:     MainController.setup_connections called with args <controllers.main_controller.MainController(0x1699fdcdda0) at 0x000001699F793300>
2024-07-29 16:52:26,645: DEBUG:     MainController.setup_connections returned None
2024-07-29 16:52:26,646: DEBUG: MainController.initialize_components returned None

Which is better than nothing, but not quite what I want. How can I update this (ideally without using a global variable) to have variable indentation at the start of each line of logger output?

This idea seems dubious.  The call stack may be really deep in some cases (e.g. recursive functions) .

In this case it will never go very deep, it’sa gui app so just a few levels in event handlers and no recursion

Maybe you should include your formatters. Stdlib formatters don't have set_tabs / get_tabs methods.

I got it working, will post the hack soon - not pretty but it works

I ended up using a not quite global variable to achieve this by setting an attribute directing in logging.root:
        setattr(logging.root, 'indent', 0)
        setattr(logging.root, 'tab_spaces', 4)
        setattr(logging.root, 'extra', {'tabs': ' '*(0)})
        
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(tabs)%(asctime)s: %(levelname)s:s%(message)s")
        formatter = logging.Formatter("%%(tabs)(asctime)s: %(levelname)s:%(message)s", defaults={'tabs': ''})
        
        root_logger = logging.getLogger()

        #console logger
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        root_logger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

the log_decorator now updates that property to maintain a globally accessible record of the local indentation level
def log(_func=None, *, logger):
    def decorator_log(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                indent = logger.root.indent
                tab_spaces = logger.root.tab_spaces
                tabs = ' '*(indent * tab_spaces)
                logger.root.indent += 1
                subtabs = ' '*((indent+1) * tab_spaces)
                logger.root.extra = {'tabs': subtabs}
                self = args[0]
                name = f'{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}'
                if logger.root.level > logging.DEBUG:
                    logger.info(f"Entering {name}", extra={'tabs': tabs})
                else:
                    args_repr = [repr(a) for a in args]
                    kwargs_repr = [f"{k}={v!r}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
                    signature = ", ".join(args_repr + kwargs_repr)
                    logger.debug(f"{name} called with args ({signature})", extra={'tabs': tabs})
            except:
                pass
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(f"Exception raised in {name}: {str(e)}", extra={'tabs': tabs})
                raise e
            else:
                if logger.root.level > logging.DEBUG:
                    logger.info(f"Leaving {name}", extra={'tabs': tabs})
                else:
                    logger.debug(f"{name} returned ({result})", extra={'tabs': tabs})
                logger.root.indent -= 1
            return result
        return wrapper
    if _func is None:
        return decorator_log
    else:
        return decorator_log(_func)

Now, any time you want to log something in a class and respect the local indentation level, get the logger as a class variable and call it with the extra arg.
def DummyClass():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    ...
    logger.info('msg', extra=self.logger.root.extra)

Not pretty, but it works and will not throw errors if you decide not to respect the indentation.
NOTE: this is -very- not thread safe
